# in_array function in php not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
//codeigniter array passed form controller to view    
$data['combined_array'] = array('75x35' => $output,'20x5' => $output1);

$all_dates = Array ('2019-11-19','2019-11-20', '2019-11-21','2019-11-22' );

foreach($combined_array as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
        {
            if($value2['size'] == '20x5'){
                if(in_array($value2['date'], $all_dates))
                {
                  echo "exists -".$value2['date'];
                }
                else
                {
                  echo "doesnt exists -".$value2['date'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$value2['date']` contains the values `2019-11-20, 2019-11-21,2019-11-22`. i want to check if all the values in all_dates exists in `$value2['date']`. if not then echo doesn't exists. but my code doesn't work.

```
var_export($combined_array)
array ( '75x35' => array ( '2019-11-19' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '75x35', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-19', 'stock_out' => '4', ), ), '2019-11-20' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '75x35', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-20', 'stock_out' => '6', ), ), '2019-11-21' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '75x35', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-21', 'stock_out' => '5', ), ), '2019-11-22' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '75x35', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-22', 'stock_out' => '5', ), ), ), '20x5' => array ( '2019-11-20' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '20x5', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-20', 'stock_out' => '2', ), ), '2019-11-21' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '20x5', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-21', 'stock_out' => '1', ), ), '2019-11-22' => array ( 0 => array ( 'size' => '20x5', 'category' => 'steel', 'type' => 'structural', 'sub_type' => 'flats', 'date' => '2019-11-22', 'stock_out' => '3', ), ), ), )
```

Comment: what is in `$combined_array` array?

Comment: show us the value of `var_export($combined_array);`

Comment: Your code is [ok](https://3v4l.org/PX7G2). You did what you wanted.

Comment: but my code is not displaying else part. '2019-11-19' is not there in $value2['date']. so else part should execute for this date.

Comment: @hytsan, [like this](https://3v4l.org/5Wr08)?

Comment: @AksenP i tried your code but still the same thing. else part not getting executed.

Comment: @hytsan, but you can see that it is executing.

Comment: @AksenP else part doesnt execute when i put if($value2['size'] == '20x5') condition. https://3v4l.org/1amWO

Comment: @hytsan, clearly look at an example over the link. If you'll define size -> you'll get result only for records corresponding to this size.

Comment: i want the output that way

Comment: If you only want the dates from that particular size, I've added an edit to my answer which shows how you can do it without the loop.

Comment: @hytsan, I've updated answer. Check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [checking each](https://3v4l.org/5Wr08) `date` value of each `size` row replace your `if` statement with a new one:

```
$temp = [];
foreach($combined_array as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {

        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
        {

            //if($value2['size'] == '20x5'){
            if (!in_array($value2['date'],$temp)){

                $temp[] = $value2['date'];

                if(in_array($value2['date'], $all_dates))
                {  
                  echo "exists -".$value2['date'];
                  echo "\r\n";
                }
                else
                { 
                  echo "doesnt exists -".$value2['date'];
                  echo "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**
Or you can check `all_dates` values on existing inside defined `size`:

```
$temp = [];

foreach($combined_array as $key => $value){

    if($key == '20x5') { 

        $temp = array_keys($value); 

        $diff = array_diff($all_dates, $temp);

        foreach($all_dates as $date)
        { 
            echo !in_array($date, $diff) ? "exists -".$date.PHP_EOL : "doesnt exists -".$date.PHP_EOL;  
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GGvDY)

Comment: i need to access $value2['stock_out'] in the if part. like if date doesnt exists, display $value2['stock_out'] empty else display its value.

Comment: yes. i am getting what i wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is for each part of the combined array is to check the difference between the list of dates ( the keys ) and the list of dates you want.  This can be done using `array_keys()` to get a list of the dates and `array_diff()` to check for  missing dates...

```
foreach( $combined_array as $key => $value){
    $dateMismatch = array_diff($all_dates, array_keys($value));
    if(count($dateMismatch) > 0 ){
        echo "Dates for {$key} missing=".implode(",", $dateMismatch).PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This just displays the differences as...

```
Dates for 20x5 missing=2019-11-19
```

for your test data.

**EDIT:**

If you just want the dates different for 1 size, then you don't need a loop, just pick out the details first using something like `$combined_array['20x5']`...

```
$dateMismatch = array_diff($all_dates, array_keys($combined_array['20x5']));
if(count($dateMismatch) > 0 ){
    echo "Dates missing=".implode(",", $dateMismatch).PHP_EOL;
}
```